# Как динамически менять параметры view элемента?

Tags: android, button, textview, switch

Предположим у меня в разметке первого фрагмента есть `button1`, а во втором фрагменте `button2`. Я хочу по нажатию на `button2` менять параметры `button1`. А конкретно:

```
android:text=""
android:background=""
```

и очень было бы хорошо, если есть такая возможность, чтобы поменять и `id`.

```
 android:id="@+id/"
```

Зачем менять `text` и `background` понятно, не обсуждается. А вот зачем менять `id` сейчас расскажу. Дело в том, что в первом фрагменте не одна кнопка button1, а две: `button0` и `button1`. Кроме кнопок в этой разметке есть и `TextView` с определенным текстом. Т.е. ни одна кнопка нажата не была. Назовем это девственное состояние `TextView` - TX-0. По нажатию на кнопку `button0` текст в `TextView` меняется. По нажатию на `button1` текст в `TextView` снова меняется. Теперь вернемся к тому моменту, когда была нажата `button0` и надо вернутся к девственному состоянию `TextView` - TX-0. Для этого я хочу поменять текст на кнопке `button0` - поскольку она уже была нажата и толку от нее теперь не больше чем от пустой банки от консервов. Допустим `text` и `background` вы мне скажете как сделать и я это пропишу в case нажатой кнопки button0.

```
  switch (view.getId()) {
                case R.id.button0:
                    mSelectedItemView2.setText(Html.fromHtml(string3, null, new MyHtmlTagHandler()));                       
                    Вот сюда пропишу 
                    break;

                case R.id.button1:
                    mSelectedItemView2.setText(Html.fromHtml(string4, null, new MyHtmlTagHandler()));
                    break;
            }
```

Но как сделать, чтобы по нажатию второй раз на эту же кнопку вернуться назад? Понятно что так не получится:

```
case R.id.button0:
                        mSelectedItemView2.setText(Html.fromHtml(string3, null, new MyHtmlTagHandler()));
                        switch (view.getId()) {
                            case R.id.button0:
                                mSelectedItemView2.setText(Html.fromHtml(string2, null, new MyHtmlTagHandler())); - (это та самая TX-0)
                                break;
                        }    
                        break;
```

Тогда у меня возникла идея поменять id и во втором switch обращаться уже не к button0, а к новому id, который я успею присвоить в case. Или это можно как-то по-другому сделать? Спасибо за помощь!

p.s. зачем я изначально говорил про второй фрагмент и button2? Тоже есть своя задумка, поэтому не лишнее.

Comment: myView.setId(); - не подходит?

Comment: каких эпических размеров велосипед вы тут придумали... Создайте себе поле `boolean isPressed`, и записывайте в него, была ли нажата кнопка, или нет. И у него и узнавайте это, когда нужно.

Comment: спасибо, boolean помогло

Answer (score 1):

Ответ по поводу как менять параметры `View` элемента из кода `Java`.

`YoursViewElement.setText("Текст");` - как поменять текст на button
`YoursViewElement.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.название рисунка/картинка);` - как поменять `background`, если речь идет не о цвете (`color`), а о рисунке/картинке из `drawable`.